# apt-get update reports GPG errors

Tags: linux, debian, apt

This is what happens when I do `apt-get update`:

```
Get:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease [68.2 kB]       
Ign:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease                     
Get:2 http://ftp.bme.hu/debian stretch InRelease [175 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [88.5 kB]
Ign:2 http://ftp.bme.hu/debian stretch InRelease                  
Ign:3 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Fetched 332 kB in 1s (175 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ftp.bme.hu/debian stretch InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Here's my `sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main non-free contrib
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main non-free contrib
```

How do I fix this? I've already tried the suggestions from [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/1059346/apt-get-update-not-working-signing-verification-errors)

Comment: Try  `sudo apt-key update && sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Tried it, didn't change anything.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Yeah, upgrading solved the problem. I was wary to do it because of the GPG error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Warning: 'apt-key update' is deprecated and should not be used anymore!
Note: In your distribution this command is a no-op and can therefore be removed safely."
dist-upgrade indicates I'm on the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments : The problem is solved by upgrading packages :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 7):

Debian has deployed new keys to sign their packages and lists, to solve the error you need the latest version of "debian-archive-keyring". upgrade that package.

```
# apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
```

Comment: Did that, it didn't help.